# php - Codeigniter Increment

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

So I have this function that gets the total number of rows in a table.

**This is my Code:**

```
public function get_reservation()
    {
        $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as res_no ');
        $this->db->from('reservation_details');
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        echo json_encode($query);
    }
```

And it returns this **JSON data**

```
[{"res_no":"2"}]
```

What I want is to increment its value to 1 and return like this

```
[{"res_no":"3"}]
```

So far I have tried something like this

**This is the my Code:**

```
public function get_reservation()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as res_no ')->from('reservation_details')->get();
        $price =  $query->row()->res_no;
        $price = $price + 1;
        echo json_encode($price);
    }
```

But it only return `3`

Comment: can you past here value of var_dump($price);

Comment: it returns something like this int(3), how do I make it something like this `[{"res_no":"3"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Use CI query helper `count_all` to count all record of a table*

```
public function get_reservation()
{
    $count = $this->db->count_all('reservation_details');
    $price = $count + 1;
    $data['res_no'] = $price;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html#information-about-your-database